# Spring Boot w/Java 11 - Execution failed for task ':bootRun'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11

Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE
Gradle 5.4.1

I've got a spring boot app that I would like to get running on Java 11. Works fine with Java 8 as is. I modified the `build.gradle` to use Java 11 for source target. When running the `bootRun` gradle task, I'm now getting the following stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
14:14:16.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
14:14:16.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/greggb/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.3-zulu/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:396)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:38)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:81)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun.exec(BootRun.java:51)
14:14:16.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
14:14:16.310 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
14:14:16.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
14:14:16.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 35 more
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:14:16.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Just looks like a bunch of internal Gradle stuff that I can't interpret. Also, I have a try/catch around my `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` but it doesn't even get that far. At a loss here. Works fine under Java 1.8.

EDIT:

Upon more evaluation, I've found the culprit:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Removing that allows the app to run, but then my app fails because of properties that I load into my config files. I'm now searching to see if there is a different process I need to use here.

Comment: Have you tried the latest 2.1.4 Spring Boot release?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, yes I did. Same results. I'm filing through my dependencies to see what it could be but the fact that it never even gets into the `main` method has be baffled. A blank start.spring.io app works fine with Java 11.

Comment: We have what you've shared so far. We have the „*`Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/greggb/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.3-zulu/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`*“ from the stack trace. What we have points to it being either *something* specific to your application or *something* specific to your environment. Without any additional details about those unknowns, the best anybody can offer at this point would be wild guesses :) Can you push to github a simple replica that reproduces the problem? Or post your full *`build.gradle`* here?

Comment: For all intent and purposes the problem is solved, though I just don't know why the particular solution fixed the problem. I'll provide an answer for it shortly, and then I'll probably open a new question to address it specifically. At that point I may be able to provide a small working example.

Comment: @Gregg Solution(s), please?